# Why does this query crash if there are no matching results instead of returning an empty result?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using this query to get some statistics from our DB

```
SELECT DateTimePart("yyyy", c.RedeemedDate) AS RedeemedInYear,
       DateTimePart("m", c.RedeemedDate) AS RedeemedInMonth,
       AVG(c.RedPriceStoreSummary ?? c.WhitePriceStoreSummary) AS AverageBasketValue
FROM c
WHERE c.IsRedeemed = true
AND c.Brand = 'xxx'
AND c.RedeemedDate != null
AND DateTimePart("yyyy", c.RedeemedDate) = DateTimePart("yyyy", GetCurrentDateTime())
GROUP BY DateTimePart("m", c.RedeemedDate),
DateTimePart("yyyy", c.RedeemedDate)
```

The problem is that query crashes with the following error if there are no results

```
Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

If I force the query to where it gets results then everything works fine but I dont want the query to crash if there are no results I want an empty result set.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap queries in a try block and catch if it returns a 404. This is a hold over in behavior from the previous SDK. Alternatively you can use the stream variant of these SDK functions which will not throw exceptions when data is not found, however you still want to check the http response code and you'll also need to manually deserialize the data.